# Are nodejs modules cached across multiple HTTP requests?

Tags: node.js

The nodejs documentation says

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. 
>   This means (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get
>   exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same
>   file.

But it does not specify the scope. Are loaded modules cached for multiple calls to require('module') in the current HTTP request or across multiple HTTP requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are.

Unlike other common server environments, like PHP,
a node.js server will not shut down after a request is done.

Suppose you are using the excellent [express](http://expressjs.com) framework, maybe this example will help to understand the difference:

```
... // setup your server

// do a route, that will show a call-counter
var callCount = {};

app.get('/hello/:name', function(request, response) {
  var name = request.params.name;
  callCount[name] = (callCount[name] || 0) + 1

  response.send(
    "Hello " + name + ", you invoked this " + callCount[name] + " times");
  });
});
```

When calling `curl localhost:3000/hello/Dave` you will receive a higher number with every subsequent call.

1st call: `Hello Dave, you invoked this 1 times`

2nd call: `Hello Dave, you invoked this 2 times`

... and so on ...

So your `callCount` will be modified by any request to that route. It does not matter where it comes from, and it could be defined in any module you're `require`ing.

Anyway, those variables, defined in any module, will be reset when the server restarts.
You can counter that by putting them into a Store, that is separated from you node.js process, like a [Redis](http://redis.io/) Store (see [node-redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis)), a file on your file-system or a database, like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/). In the end it's up to you. You just need to be aware of where your data comes from and goes to.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Also from the docs:

```
    Multiple calls to require('foo') may not cause the module code to be executed 
    multiple times. This is an important feature. With it, "partially done" 
    objects can be returned, thus allowing transitive dependencies to be loaded 
    even when they would cause cycles. If you want to have a module execute code 
    multiple times, then export a function, and call that function.
```

Comment: The docs do not specify whether the caching is across multiple HTTP requests or multiple calls to require('foo') for the current HTTP requests.

Comment: Oh. The docs may not be super clear but they are cached for multiple requests. :)